# Getting problem for picker view

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am implementing picker view with double component Toggle with  Celsius and Fahrenheit  two picker views by selecting toggle button. Both the picker view is loading my app and getting toggle . But i am missing my components values ., please help me , here i attached my picker  project.

http://www.ziddu.com/download/13259414/TemperaturePicker.zip.html

Comment: Please copy here the relevant part of the code or the part you think is wrong so we all can see it faster. sometimes we are not at a place we can run Xcode projects ;)

Comment: What your saying is correct and i  understood . But here i found out problem is loading pickerview  and i created both temperatures are NSOject , better looking sample easily get solution i posted . i got solution  from @phix23.Thanks for looking my question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found two problems in your code:

- In the method `updateLabel` you should reload the pickerview:

  `[pickerView reloadAllComponents];`
- Your `NSObject`-Classes `Celsius` and `Fahrenheit` are not ViewControllers, which means that `viewDidLoad` won't be executed and the array containing the data will not be initialized.

Better you write an initializer like this:

```
- (id)init {        
       /* initialize data-arrays here */
       return self;             
}
```

Comment: Yes . Now working , I accepted your answer and voted for you. Thanks for spending valuable time to look my code.